# ADFS Sign-in page won't load custom font

Tags: customization, adfs3.0

I am customizing my ADFS 3.0 sign-in page and I have created a custom theme and modified the stylesheet to add a new font family (FontAwesome).  Here is the font definition in the stylesheet.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('./fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.6.3');
  src: url('./fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.6.3') format('embedded-opentype'), url('./fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.6.3') format('woff2'), url('./fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.6.3') format('woff'), url('./fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.6.3') format('truetype'), url('./fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.6.3#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

I executed the following Powershell commands to add the additional resource files to ADFS (I even tried to add the ?v=4.6.3 to the Uri but still got the same errors ):

```
Set-AdfsWebTheme -TargetName CustomerPortal -AdditionalFileResource @{Uri="/adfs/portal/css/fontawesome-webfont.woff";path="C:\ADFS_CustomerPortal_Theme\css\fontawesome-webfont.woff"}
Set-AdfsWebTheme -TargetName CustomerPortal -AdditionalFileResource @{Uri="/adfs/portal/css/fontawesome-webfont.woff2";path="C:\ADFS_CustomerPortal_Theme\css\fontawesome-webfont.woff2"}
Set-AdfsWebTheme -TargetName CustomerPortal -AdditionalFileResource @{Uri="/adfs/portal/css/fontawesome-webfont.ttf";path="C:\ADFS_CustomerPortal_Theme\css\fontawesome-webfont.ttf"}
Set-AdfsWebTheme -TargetName CustomerPortal -AdditionalFileResource @{Uri="/adfs/portal/css/fontawesome-webfont.eot";path="C:\ADFS_CustomerPortal_Theme\css\fontawesome-webfont.eot"}
Set-AdfsWebTheme -TargetName CustomerPortal -AdditionalFileResource @{Uri="/adfs/portal/css/fontawesome-webfont.svg";path="C:\ADFS_CustomerPortal_Theme\css\fontawesome-webfont.svg"}
Set-AdfsWebTheme -TargetName CustomerPortal -AdditionalFileResource @{Uri="/adfs/portal/css/fontawesome.otf";path="C:\ADFS_CustomerPortal_Theme\css\fontawesome.otf"}
```

When I refresh my sign-in page I get the following errors in the console.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi! Did you manage to solve it? @HisDivineShadow

Comment: @mr3k Unfortunately, no.  We changed what we wanted the page to look like and didn't require the font anymore.  I moved on from that project a long time ago and haven't worked with ADFS since.  I'm surprised that there hasn't been a solution posted by now, maybe you can be the hero that figures it out.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and found that ADFS's custom themes cannot actually serve font files: there's nothing in the documentation on this, but Microsoft confirmed that in the answer to [this question](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/af060212-5d8b-440d-86e1-72dcb2f6d92e/adfs-theme-is-not-serving-a-font-file?forum=ADFS).

They do suggest a workaround, where you use a `.css` extension for the URI but actually use your font file as the path:

```
Set-AdfsWebTheme -TargetName Custom -AdditionalFileResource @{Uri="/adfs/portal/vegan.css";Path="C:\webtheme\css\Vegan.ttf"}
```